# How to make custom response in Nestjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, response

I need custom response to all my controllers, how to make this real?

I have format like this:
**Success response**

```
{
  status: string,
  code: number,
  message: string
  data: object | array | any,
  request: {
    url: string,
    method: string
  }
}
```

**Exception response**

```
{
  status: string,
  code: number,
  message: string
  error: object | array | any,
  request: {
    url: string,
    method: string
  }
}
```

How can I implement it in Nestjs?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the controller function you can just return your objects:

```
@Get('path')
async getResponse() {
  if(success) {
    return {
      status: string,
      code: number,
      message: string
      data: object | array | any,
      request: {
        url: string,
        method: string
      }
  } else if (error) {
    return {
      status: string,
      code: number,
      message: string
      error: object | array | any,
      request: {
        url: string,
        method: string
      }
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can also use the expressjs Reponse and Request objects as described in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#routing).

If you want to make use of type safety, you can specify your response types in another file, like so:

response.interface.ts

```js
export interface SuccessResponse = {
  status: string,
  code: number,
  message: string
  data: object | array | any,
  request: {
    url: string,
    method: string
  }
}

export type ErrorResponse = {
  status: string,
  code: number,
  message: string
  error: object | array | any,
  request: {
    url: string,
    method: string
  }
}
```

And then in your controller:

```js
@Get('path')
async getResponse(): SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse { ... }
```

Comment: Hi @fonzane, thanks for your reply, but I need best practice what nestjs do

Comment: This is best practice. Look at the docs, I provided a link.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) that does some response mapping for you so that you can just return the data and the interceptor can format it for all endpoints. For exceptions, I  would create an explicit [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) that does something similar. Both of these should have access to the `ArgumentHost`/`ExecutionContext` which can be used to get the `request` and `response` object so you have access to things like the url and method, the current status code, and whatever else you may need.